# Is it possible to replace a laptop screen with a different refresh rate?

Tags: laptop, display, refresh-rate, replacement

Suppose, currently, my screen has a 144Hz refresh rate and I want to replace it with a 120 Hz refresh rate screen. Is this possible? I've heard that it is not possible. If it is so, why does it say that it is compatible with 120Hz screen?
[image: 1]

By the way, the laptop I'm referring to is an **Acer Nitro 5**

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that on an Acer Nitro 5. What, you want proof? Ok sure. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-RQX_dgq7Y But a 144Hz refresh rate is better than a 120Hz refresh rate so I am not sure why you would prefer the 120Hz version.

There is a chance that you can simply set the display to 120Hz, and that that is what they mean with "compatible with 120Hz". https://www.howtogeek.com/267650/how-to-make-your-120hz-or-144hz-monitor-use-its-advertised-refresh-rate/

Comment: The screen I have currently is a 144Hz one which is not working. However, I've got a screen for the laptop which is 120Hz. Is this replacement possible?

Comment: @S.Tiss which screen is it?

Comment: Both screens are for Acer Nitro-5. The screen to be replaced is 144Hz. This is to be replaced by one having 120Hz.